# Uploading multiple files from a File Input control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Using this on an ASPX page using ASP.net 4.0

```
<input type="file" id="File1" name="myfiles" multiple="multiple" runat="server">
```

I want something like this in VB code

```
For Each File in File1
    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(savePath & File1.Value)
```

However, I can't figure out the syntax for that to work. Googling results only in jquery plugins and scripts, and I don't want all that if I could just get it to work with what I have already.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty simple thing to do.

ASP.NET 4.0- Method..

Your HTML markup for your file uploader should read as:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file1" runat="server" />
```

When your code is submitted, you can access the posted files using the following logic:

```
    Dim f As HttpPostedFile
    For i As UInt16 = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1
        f = Request.Files(i)
        'Your logic here....
    Next
```

ASP.NET 4.5+ Method...

Your HTML markup for your file uploader should read as:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="file1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

Then, when your form is submitted, just use code similar to:

```
For Each f In file1.PostedFiles
    'Your logic here..
Next
```

That logic will allow you to iterate through each file uploaded via the control.  Each "PostedFile" is of type "HttpPostedFile", which will give you all sorts of properties on the name, content length, extension and filebytes.

Hope this helps, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using ASP.NET 4.0, and that feature is only available in 4.5, so I am unable to use it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Im sorry, what's only available in 4.5?  The file upload control has been in the framework since 2.0...

Comment: AllowMultiple is only an attribute of FileUpload in 4.5, earlier versions do not allow it.

Comment: i use it from 3.5 :) my example above was done in 3.5

Comment: @Blake please see my updated answer, I just think you need to access the HTTPFileCollection to get these files..

Comment: What do you mean "access the HTTPFileCollection"? I put in your code, and it just saves 1 file only, so it still isn't grabbing the group of files.

Comment: @Blake please set a breakpoint and take a look at what Request.Files contains.  I just tried this code and it did work, I was able to select 2 files in the "browse" window for files, submit my form, and 2 files were in the "Request.Files" HttpFileCollection

Comment: I am not sure how to check the contents of Request.Files. However, I am stopping for now, and will start again tomorrow! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sure thing @Blake.  By that, I mean set a break point, submit your form, and perform a quickwatch on Request.Files and look at the properties of that object.  Does it have files in it.. what's the count property like, etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is more simple take a look here :

```
  <td>                                            
  <asp:FileUpload runat="server"   ID="FileUpload1" AllowMultiple="true" name="files[]"         onchange="handleFileSelect(this)" />
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="filesToIgnore"  />
     <div style="float:right;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddSubArticle" Text="Aggiungi"  />
     </div>
  </td>
```

then javascript to your stuff in example from muy previous project:

```
   <!-- The necessary scripts that do work son. -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        // FileList object
        //var files = evt.target.files;
        var files = evt.files;
        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) { continue; }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.id = "span-img";
                    // Creates a thumbnail with an onclick function that will handle the mock deletion
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img data-id="img' + new Date().getTime() + '" class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                      '"title="', escape(theFile.name), '"onclick="deleteImage(this);" />'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);
            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
    //The image was clicked delete it
    function deleteImage(imgToDelete) {
        try {
            var fu = document.getElementById('<%=filesToIgnore.ClientID.ToString%>')
            fu.value += (imgToDelete.title + ",");
            imgToDelete.style.display = 'none';
        }
        catch (err)
        { alert(err); }
    }

</script>
```

Then server side(there's a little bit more code for some stuff in here take a look into this and modify it as per your need)

```
    Dim NewLine As String = "<br/>"
    Dim ListFiles As New List(Of String)
    Dim ignoredFiles As String() = filesToIgnore.Value.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each el In FileUpload1.PostedFiles
        If Not ignoredFiles.Any(Function(x) el.FileName.Contains(x)) Then
            Select Case Path.GetExtension(el.FileName.ToString.ToLower)

                Case ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".tiff", ".bmp", ".gif"
                    Try
                        Dim P As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/") & el.FileName.ToString
                        el.SaveAs(P)
                        Dim F As New FileInfo(P)
                        'Dim NewName As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString & F.Extension.ToString
                        'ListFiles.Add(NewName)
                        '*****************************AZIONI DI RIDIMENSIONAMENTO E WATERMARK*******************************'
                        ' Dim img As New Bitmap(P)
                        Dim imgResizer As New ProtectedImage(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/"), P, Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/th/"), Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/w/watermark.png"), Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/w/watermark.png"), 400, 400, 80, True, GetNumber, ddlDomainMicroArticle.SelectedItem.ToString)
                        imgResizer.GenerateImages()
                        If imgResizer.StateWork = ProtectedImage.workState.WorkCompleted Then
                            lbl.Text = "Watermark e Resize completati" & NewLine
                        Else
                            lbl.Text = "Errore durante l'elaborazione dell'immagine" & NewLine
                        End If
                        '*****************************AZIONI DI RIDIMENSIONAMENTO E WATERMARK*******************************'
                        Dim ResizedImage As String = imgResizer.FileList.Item(1).ToString
                        Dim Thumbnails As String = imgResizer.FileList.Item(2).ToString
                        ListFiles.Add(ResizedImage)
                        ListFiles.Add(Thumbnails)
                        If MoveToCDN(ResizedImage, Thumbnails) Then
                            lbl.Text = lbl.Text & el.FileName & " Caricata" & NewLine
                        Else
                            lbl.Text = lbl.Text & el.FileName & " Fallita" & NewLine
                        End If

                        imgResizer.Dispose()
                        ' Elimina l 'eventuale watermark se esiste
                        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/w/watermark.png")) Then
                            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/w/watermark.png"))
                        End If
                        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/" & Replace(ResizedImage, "rs_", ""))) Then
                            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/" & Replace(ResizedImage, "rs_", "")))
                        End If
                        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/th/" & Replace(Thumbnails, "th_", ""))) Then
                            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/img/th/" & Replace(Thumbnails, "th_", "")))
                        End If
                        If File.Exists(P) Then
                            File.Delete(P)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        lbl.Text = lbl.Text & ex.Message & NewLine
                    End Try
                Case Else
                    lbl.Text = lbl.Text & el.FileName.ToString & " Estensione file non consentita" & NewLine
            End Select
        End If
    Next
```

I hope that is usefully

Comment: That hardly looks "simple". Looks like a lot of fluff that I don't need.

Comment: and I can't use <asp:FileUpload> because AllowMultiple is not available in ASP.net 4.0

Comment: again :) it is done in 3.5 and if i can do it how can you're not however in this example you have a complete and working example for many stuff.you can bring what you need and modify.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 3.5? Try checking your framework in your project properties.

Comment: Blake you're right it was modify from 3.5 to 4.5 .....it is not working in previous framework.....i'm sorry